# ANTLR : Have errors with Fragment

Tags: antlr4

[image]

[image]

The error is :

```
mismatched input 'elseState' expecting RULE_TOKEN_REF
```

Can someone explain to me why do i have this error and how to fix it ?

Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments are reserved to lexer rules definition and are not usable for parser rules, you don't need it in your case.

A fragment is used to split complex lexer rules and introduce reusability without producing a dedicated token, e.g.:

```
NUMBER : DIGIT+;  
ID : LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

In these lexer rules, I don't want `LETTER` and `DIGIT` as token, however, I want to use and reuse them in other lexer rules (`NUMBER` and `DIGIT`), so I 'mark' them as `fragment`. It makes the lexer more readable and easier to maintain.

You can read more details here: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules